# Error "EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto\evp\evp_enc.c:570" appears even after specifying -md5 sha256 in command line

Tags: encryption, ffmpeg, openssl, md5, sha

I have the following query. Could anyone please suggest me a solution.

I'm working on decryption of .ts file for the first time. I have downloaded multiple .ts files from the source and have merged them but not able to decrypt the file. Even if it gets decrypted the size of the file is zero bytes.

Command I'm using:

```
aes-128-cbc -d -in D:\Test\joined_files.ts -out D:\Test\decrypt_I00100000.ts -iv 0 -K 313863756468736b63646b6a616b -md SHA256
```

The error I'm getting:

the hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to the length
the hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to the length
bad decrypt
1132:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto\evp\evp_enc.c:570:
error in aes-128-cbc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeRLG.png)

Comment: If your decryption is not succeeding, the first thing to do is double check how it was **en**crypted. We'll need to know that too.

Comment: My challenge is to download this video:   https://11k.phando.com/

Comment: Your key looks suspect. For AES-128 you would expect a 128-bit key (16 bytes). Your key is 14 bytes (28 hex digits). Hence the error about "hex string is too short"

Comment: @JamesKPolk and Matt ,Is there any way I can download this video: https://11k.phando.com/ I have downloaded the key file from this url from Network's tab. Also, Just came to know the encryption used is "Elliptic Curve"